# Wordpress plugin HTML is not rendering correctly

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to put my mobile menu in a plugin but the html is not working correctly.

Here is my plugin code:

```
function mobile_menu_function() {
  $menu_html = '<div class="toggle-button">'.
                '<div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>'.
                '<div class="menu-bar menu-bar-middle"></div>'.
                '<div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>'.
            '</div>'.
            '<div class="menu-wrap">'.
                '<div class="mobile-menu-sidebar">' . wp_nav_menu( array("container_class" => "mobile-menu-class", "theme_location" => "primary") ) . '</div>'.
            '</div>';
 return $menu_html;
}
```

But when I view my html in developer tools, the menu "mobile-menu-class" in not in the "menu-wrap" div, it's now located above "toggle-button"?

Here is how the html looks:

```
<div class="mobile-menu-class">...</div>
<div class="toggle-button">...</div>
<div class="menu-wrap">...</div>
```

How can I get the menu in the "menu-wrap" div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/), you need to add `'echo' => false` to the arguments of `wp_nav_menu`:

```
return  wp_nav_menu( array("container_class" => "mobile-menu-class", "theme_location" => "primary", "echo" => false) );
```

Otherwise this function echos the HTML directly instead of returning it.